# Pyspark String and list of objects

Tags: python, xml, apache, data-analysis, apache-spark-sql

I have a string with a

https://hdchjhjedjekdn.com/{}_public.xml with a place holder and I have list of objects

201611339349202661,
 201611309349201761,
 201543179349200944,
 201631099349200733,
 201610909349200511,
 201630749349201058,
 201601319349200235,
 201641069349200909,
 201542999349200004,
 201611319349201771,
 201641329349200119,
 201513219349200536,
 201543159349201769,
 201612029349200631,
 201621339349202247,
 201611259349200506,
 201611829349200301,
 201543169349201114,
 201543209349204979,
 201641039349200509,
 201621309349200642,
 201512789349200031,
 201601939349200520

I would like to fill the placeholder with the list of objects.

Like:

s = (https://hdchjhjedjekdn.com/201611339349202661_public.xml, https://hdchjhjedjekdn.com/201611309349201761_public.xml, https://hdchjhjedjekdn.com/201543179349200944_public.xml,........)

Any help would be appreciated using **pyspark**

Comment: Is the list a python list or an RDD?

Comment: I can say it is a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parallelize your list of ids and broadcast the url string across workers. Then apply map to create the formatted string,

```
>>>l = [201611339349202661, 201611309349201761, 201543179349200944, 201631099349200733, 201610909349200511, 201630749349201058, 201601319349200235, 201641069349200909, 201542999349200004, 201611319349201771, 201641329349200119, 201513219349200536, 201543159349201769, 201612029349200631, 201621339349202247, 201611259349200506, 201611829349200301, 201543169349201114, 201543209349204979, 201641039349200509, 201621309349200642, 201512789349200031, 201601939349200520]
>>>rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
>>>rdd.getNumPartitions()
12 ## I have used 12 workers
>>>brd_url = sc.broadcast('https://hdchjhjedjekdn.com/{}_public.xml')
>>>rdd1 = rdd.map(lambda x:brd_url.value.format(x))
>>>rdd1.take(2)
['https://hdchjhjedjekdn.com/201611339349202661_public.xml', 'https://hdchjhjedjekdn.com/201611309349201761_public.xml']
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A simple list comprehension should do the trick since it is not an RDD -

```
url_mod = ["https://hdchjhjedjekdn.com/{}_public.xml".format(x) for x in ids]
```

Comment: Since ids is a list it is giving me an error “list” object has no attribute “map”